# Padding on ProgressBar background programmatically

Tags: android, background, progress-bar, padding

I have created a ProgressBar which uses this progressDrawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/checkoutBackground"/>
        <stroke android:color="@color/white" android:width="2dp" />
        <padding android:top="6dp" android:bottom="6dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="6dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%" >
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            </shape>
        </scale>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

but apparently there is a bug on Android API 21 that ignores the padding that I placed on the background.

I want to reach that background and set it's padding programmatically.

```
    progressBar.findViewById(android.R.id.background).setPadding();
```

but I get a nullPointerException

Any other ways I might try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove android:id="@android:id/progress"

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from this answer: [Padding on Shape in Progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034610/padding-on-shape-in-progressbar)

Amazingly the issue is fixed by removing the id: android:id="@android:id/progress"